# How do I get Azure DevOps releases for a particular repository via the DevOps APIs?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm working on automating approvals of DevOps releases through another system. The problem is, I need to be able to identify which releases are on pipeline(s) built from a particular repository; I'm fine with having to make multiple API calls to get the right identifiers but I don't see any APIs where I can get information on the repository a pipeline is built on.

(Unfortunately my organization places multiple repositories per project so I can't do it with just the project specifier).

Is there some DevOps API I missed that I can get down to the level of info on which repository the pipeline uses?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Vito - apparently I did not get email notifications of answers on this. Thanks, your answer looks like it should work - I actually worked the same thing out myself. Will not have a chance to implement it until later but I'll come back and edit at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create release pipeline and then we need to select the Artifacts, we could select Build or Azure Repo Git

[image]

If you are select Azure Repo Git

We could get the release repo info via this REST API [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and then search artifacts in the response body, then we could get the release repo info

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.1-preview.8
```

Result:

[image]

If you are using Build as the artifact, we could get the build info, such as build ID, build definition ID and build definition name, check the pic below:

[image]

Then run this REST API [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get the build detail info

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

[image]

And search repository in the response body to get the repo info

[image]